# Android layout <include>, does it support orientation layout xml files? Does -land work at all?

Tags: android, android-layout

This is kind of frustrating. I was trying to come up with a layout approved way of re-orienting a toolbar of buttons along the top horizontally when in portrait, and along the right vertically when in landscape. e.g. I want a row of action buttons to get out of the way depending on the orientation.

First I didn't want to duplicate all of the activity_main.xml layout content in a layout-land version of it, so I tried using the  element to point to a toolbar.xml layout and layout-land version of it.

```
/res
  /layout
    /activity_main.xml
    /toolbar.xml
  /layout-land
    /toolbar.xml
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/rootview"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context=".MainActivity">
...
<include android:id="@+id/toolbar" layout="@layout/toolbar"/>
...
```

toolbar.xml:

```
    <ToggleButton
      android:id="@+id/serviceToggleButton"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
      android:text="Port!" />
...
```

layout-land/toolbar.xml:

```
    <ToggleButton
      android:id="@+id/serviceToggleButton"
      android:layout_width="64dip"
      android:layout_height="64dip"
      android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
      android:text="Land!" />
...
```

Doesn't work. When the tablet's orientation changes, I get the same button text "Port!", and the "Land!" button text never appears. e.g. I changed the button text just in case my LinearLayout attributes didn't align as I expected.

SO! I tried going with all the land/port examples which depict primary layout xml files, and junk the use of . I created a layout-land copy of activity_main.xml and adjusted the layout for how I expected it to appear in landscape. (I removed the  as well)

```
/res
  /layout
    /activity_main.xml
  /layout-land
    /activity_main.xml
```

Doesn't work. I now have a clean portrait and landscape activity_main.xml with noticeable differences that don't appear when my orientation changes.

What gives? Anyone have any suggestions? BTW, in this case I'm stuck with Android 2.3.4. Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you the configChanges flag in the AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: I have android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"> in my AndroidManifest.xml for the <activity> MainActivity. That should be fine right?

Comment: No it is not. If you want to use layout-land you have to remove those flags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the activity in the manifest remove the orientation flag,...then your activity will destroy and recreate itself on rotation giving you the correctly included layout.

`android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"`

If you leave it in, it is up to YOU to handle the orientation change with code.

Comment: Thanks! Out of the 4 tutorials and docs I referenced, none of them mentioned about the orientation override/implementation. I'll keep this one in my memory banks.

Comment: I'm wanting to do the same thing you were originally after (having a single element switch between portrait and landscape implementations). Am I right in understanding from this that that's just never going to work?