# Switch LinearLayout from horizontal to vertical on orientation change

Tags: android

My app has various LinearLayouts which I'd like to be vertical in portrait orientation, and horizontal in landscape. I know I can manually track onLayoutChange and change them in code, but this makes them harder to work with in the XML editor and I can't help feeling there should be an easier way. What I'd really like is something like:

```
  <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation_when_in_portrait="vertical"
            android:orientation_when_in_landscape="horizontal" >
```

I realise this doesn't exist, but is there any way that this can be achieved? I can't help thinking that there might be a way to do this with RelativeLayout that I'm missing.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend reading the [providing resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) guide on the Android Developer website. You might be particularly interested [in this section.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#OrientationQualifier)

To more directly answer you question. You would be able to attain the behavior you want by copying your current layout xml file into a new folder titled "layout-land" and changing the necessary attributes of the `LinearLayout`. This is the folder that will be used by Android to load your layout files if the device is in landscape mode. If it cannot find a given xml file in the "layout-land" folder then it will default to the "layout" folder.

Comment: Apologies - I should have mentioned that I also don't want to create an alternate layout (it's a very large layout, and this is the only aspect of it that would change).

Comment: Would you be alright with separating that particular LinearLayout and its children into its own xml file (that you then alter and place in both of the necessary layout folders), and then including the LinearLayout using an `include` tag?

Comment: Ooh... if I do <include layout="@layout/myspecialone"/> then it'll include layout-land/myspecialone if I'm in landscape? I think that would definitely work...

Comment: I'm actually not 100% sure that will work, but it seems like it would. One way to find out, right?

Comment: From the look of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17324110/android-layout-include-does-it-support-orientation-layout-xml-files-does-la I think it's not going to work. Nice idea though. :(

Comment: It looks like it will work fine if you remove the `configChanges` from your manifest. That is expected behavior, because when you include the `configChanges` attribute you are essentially telling Android you'll handle things like orientation changes yourself and you don't want Android to reload resources from the necessary folders automatically.

Comment: I asked the other chap a clarifying question, but I don't think that's quite what he's saying - that's the solution to his followup problem (where his rotated layouts was never honoured at all).